# django-admin startproject results in "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'"

Tags: python, django

My setup is:
- Mac OS running pyenv installed with homebrew.
- python 3.6.5 virtualenv
- pip install Django==2.0.6

Here is the command I issued and the output.  The only answers I've found when I search for this assume an existing django project, and incorrect configuration.  I am unable to get to the point of creating the project.

```
$ django-admin startproject justatestproj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rsquire/.pyenv/versions/forever7pi/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/Users/rsquire/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/envs/forever7pi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/rsquire/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/envs/forever7pi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/rsquire/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/envs/forever7pi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/rsquire/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/envs/forever7pi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/rsquire/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/envs/forever7pi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/rsquire/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Incidentally, I get the same error when I try:

```
python -m django --version
```

However, the following works:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 26 2018, 11:45:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
2.0.6
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Is your current working directory empty?

Comment: No, it isn't.  I assumed, wrongly I think, that running:
    'django-admin startproject projectname' would create a directory called 'projectname' within my current directory.

Comment: I just created a subdirectory, and tried the same command within the new, empty directory, and got the same result.

Comment: Yes, it should create a subdirectory. I was asking to figure out if it picks up any other files it shouldn't. Check if the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is set and unset it if it is.

Comment: Thanks so much!  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE was the problem.  and now that I see the value, the error message makes total sense.

Comment: Glad I could help! I posted my comment as an answer so you can accept it to mark the question as solved :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check if the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is set and unset it if it is. E.g. in bash

```
$ unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

Comment: this didn't work for me,I still get the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users try this on the command line:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=
```